# casperjs captureSelector multiple classes as the selector

Tags: css-selectors, phantomjs, casperjs

I'm using casperJS to capture a portion of the screen using casptureSelector method with the code below:

```
    this.waitForSelector(config.selector, function () {
        this.then(function() {
                this.captureSelector(config.imageFileName, config.selector);
            });
    });
```

it is possible to pass #someId for an an id selector and .someClass for a class selector.

But how can I pass multiple classes selector like .someClass.otherClass ?

I tried many variations but I'm unable to make it work.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you can you any valid css selector so for multiple classes select you just separate the string with a comma:

`'.firstSelector, .secondSelector'`

You can't path an array but you can dynamically build with `Array.join` a string of comma separated classes

**EDIT**
I believe this would work only if the selection results in a single DOM element . If you drill into the code, the selector is used to find the capture bounds and adjust zoom., an inner method for calculating the bounds calls `findOne` with the selector, so I guess (without really digging into `findOne` method that it would return the first element if a query results in multiple DOM elements.